# How can I check two strings for similarity in php?

Tags: php, validation

Say I have two strings

```
$string1 = "Hello my name is Steve and this is spam";
$string2 = "Hello my name is Steven and this comment is spam";
```

These two strings are alike.

Is there a way to compare these, as in `if ($string1 like $string2)` in php?

Comment: You may find [`similar_text`](http://php.net/similar_text) useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate a similarity index using [the levenshtein algorithm](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php). It calculates the number of characters that need to be changed in order to transform the first input into the second, or the other way around:

```
levenshtein("bar", "baz"); // 1 character difference
levenshtein("bar", "foo"); // 3 character difference

$string1 = "Hello my name is Steve and this is spam";
$string2 = "Hello my name is Steven and this comment is spam";
levenshtein($string1, $string2); // 9 character difference
```

@TimCooper also suggested [`similar_text()`](http://php.net/similar_text), which works in a similar fashion.

Comment: Please may you provide an example?

Comment: great answer, never knew about [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php). definitely will be sure to use it in the future!

Comment: Warning: levenshtein(): Argument string(s) too long

Comment: @elusive I want to check against very long strings (1000+ chars)

Comment: @user3096443: Interesting, PHP seems to have a limit hard-coded. The algorithm itself does not have such a limitation. You could check out [`similar_text()`](http://php.net/similar_text), as @TimCooper suggested. It does not seem to have such a limit. It uses a different algorithm, though.

Answer (score -5):

Then hash the strings and compare the hash. I think thats faster than any string compare function.

Reason. String compare functions compare every character - byte by byte. A hash function takes the whole bunch of chars at once and generates its hash.

But of course you should use an "easy" hash function like md5. Not hash_pbkdf which is specialised for secure hashes. That means pbkdf computes the hash very slow so an atacker can't generate so many hashes at a given time. But thats off topic ;-)

Or:
Implement this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm or even better (faster) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: This checks for equality, not similarity.

Comment: Totally off-topic answer notwithstanding, hash functions (or at least not terrible ones) *also* take into account every character. If you look on the Wikipedia page for MD5 you see that the [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode) is *far* more complex than any pseudocode you'd get for any reasonable string comparison function. So how in the world would md5 be faster, and what's the problem with string comparisons?